# Text editor with intellisense support for web like Avalon Editor

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, intellisense, code-completion, avalonedit

I need the text editor for web (`jQuery)` with the `code completion (intelli-sense)` support like the [AvalonEditor](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/47c58b63-f30c-4290-a2f2-881d21227446.htm) for the [WPF](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/47c58b63-f30c-4290-a2f2-881d21227446.htm) framework.

Please share the suggestions.

> Requirements:
>
> 1. I will have a set of keywords, if the user types the word and it matches the keyword in the collection the intelli-sense popup should open.
> 2. it should be as you type IntelliSense and no @like character is used to invoke the popup.
> 3. it is a text editor or text area and IntelliSense popup should work on all places.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sublime Text may be used for this case. Since Javascript is basically a Interpreted language, and with its code closure function, it is hard for user to find an Javascript Editor with code completion (intelli-sense), and some need node.js to make that.